# Query Selector for Rounding UIImageViews' border

Tags: xcode, loops, uiview, properties, uiimage

I have an UIView with a set of 20 UIImageViews. The thing is: I want to give a rounded border property for each of them and I know how to do that one bye one, but don't know how to do it a loop because I need to use some kind of query selector to retrieve every image control to an array. Is there any approach for this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a nib or Storyboard... you could set the cornerRadius as a key path for the views, thus not having to do anything in code:

[image]

Comment: Or use an `IBInspectable` property, if you’re using Xcode 6.

Comment: This solution is beautiful and clean, It does not even need the clipsTobounds or maskToBounds. The only problem is that xcode does not allow to add this attributes for more than one UIImageView at the same time by selecting everyone of them and then adding the attribute. Anyway by creating one, applying the attribute and then copying it and pasting it the problem is solved. Thanks, you've opened my eyes in this...

Answer (score 1):

Put your image views in an [`IBOutletCollection`](http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/) (or an `NSArray` if you’re not using Interface Builder).

Answer (score 0):

Just name your UIImageView outlets as image1,image2,image3.....image20 etc. & You can use key value coding for rounding the corners using a for loop like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
  UIImageView *imageView = ((UIImageView *)[self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d",i+1]]);
  imageView.layer.cornerRadius = roundf(imageView.frame.size.width/2.0);
  [imageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
  [imageView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
  [imageView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
}
```

Comment: Good Solution either for those who want to add borderColor